# opencv get bounding box of two squares from image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to get the bounding boxes from an image.
I want the coordinates of the two white boxes.
This is an example image:
[image]
I tried out

```
_a, _b, stats, _c = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectivity=8)
```

and then the boxes are in the stats object.
But I got for the image more then 2 boxes. This is strange.

Maybe somebody has an other solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
import cv2

# Read image
img = cv2.imread("/Users/sb/Desktop/7n8uq.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
# Convert to grayscale
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Threshold (Produces a binary image)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(
    img_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite("thresh.png", thresh)
# Find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

print("Total number of contours: {}".format(len(contours)))

all_contours_drawn = cv2.drawContours(
    img.copy(), contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)  # draw all contours
cv2.imwrite("all_contours.png", all_contours_drawn)

box_center_x = []
box_center_y = []
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    box_center_x.append(x+w/2)
    box_center_y.append(y+h/2)

print("x-coordinate of boxes: {}".format(box_center_x))
print("y-coordinate of boxes: {}".format(box_center_y))

# Draw box centers
all_box_centers_drawn = img.copy()
for i in range(len(box_center_x)):
    cv2.circle(
        all_box_centers_drawn,
        (int(box_center_x[i]), int(box_center_y[i])),
        2, (0 , 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imwrite("box-centers.png", all_box_centers_drawn)
```

[image: centers]

Answer (score 0):

Try using find contours

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for i, contour in enumerate(contours[1::]):
    bbox = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
```

[find contours example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)